# method containing calculation - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i just want to calculate the total sum of all active events that users have paid to attend. If you could advise me i could be grateful as i am very unsure. Many thanks

```
event.rb
has_many :payments

payment
belongs_to :event
```

in the event.rb i tried the below method but no success

```
def self.active_events
    active_events = live_events.open_events
    active_events.all.each do |event|
      event.price * event.payments.count
    end
  end
```

Comment: this is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41964357/1536309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simply in following way,

```
total = 0
Event.live_events.open_events.find_each { |e| total += e.price * e.payments.count }
```

In Event.rb place it in a method with meaningful name. 
This will work for you.

```
def self.total_price_for_active_events
  total = 0
  Event.live_events.open_events.find_each { |e| total += e.price * e.payments.count }
  total
end
```

**Most optimized way**

```
def self.total_price_for_active_events
  Event.live_events.open_events.joins(:payments).sum("events.price")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're off too a good start! Unfortunately, what you have there is only the beginning; you're generating an array that contains the total sum *for each event*. All that remains is to add them together:

```
  def self.active_events
    active_events = live_events.open_events
    costs = active_events.all.each do |event|
      event.price * event.payments.count
    end
    costs.reduce(0) do |sum,x|
      sum + x
    end
  end
```

You could also get real fancy and simply use:

```
costs.reduce(0, :+)
```